# Error translating Linq expression to URI: Can only specify query options (orderby, where, take, skip) after last navigation

Tags: c#, linq, uwp, microsoft-dynamics

Im trying to fire this one simple(in my eyes) linq expression but i dont get why the hell i get this error:

```
var objekte = nav.Objekt.Where(p => p.City == "Berlin").Select(p => p.Description);
```

Comment: Is there an error in the code you posted? What are you trying to do exactly? We need more info.

Comment: I know nothing about Dynamics, but I think it doesn't like the `Select` at the end for some reason. What happens if you swap `Select` and `Where` like `nav.Objekt.Select(p => new {p.City, p.Description}).Where(p => p.City == "Berlin");`? Just curious.

Comment: @DavidG the error is in the title of my post...and the exact problem is that i just can select one dataset at the time if i filter on a primary key value but icannot get more then one result from by linq query